# File transfer using XMPPFramework

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I am using xmpp framework for my iPhone chat Application. I can able to do text chat through xmpp framework.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    TURNSocket *turnSocket = [[TURNSocket alloc] initWithStream:[self xmppStream] toJID:jid];

    [turnSockets addObject:turnSocket];

    [turnSocket startWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    [turnSocket release];

}

- (void)turnSocket:(TURNSocket *)sender didSucceed:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket {

    NSLog(@"TURN Connection succeeded!");
    NSLog(@"You now have a socket that you can use to send/receive data to/from the other person.");

    [turnSockets removeObject:sender];
}

- (void)turnSocketDidFail:(TURNSocket *)sender {

    NSLog(@"TURN Connection failed!");
    [turnSockets removeObject:sender];

}
```

But want to transfer file through xmpp framework on openfire server and failed to establish TurnSocketConnection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FileTransfer using XmppFrameWork in ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114783/filetransfer-using-xmppframework-in-ios)