# FileTransfer using XmppFrameWork in ios

Tags: ios, file-transfer, xmppframework

i have implemented some code of file transfer by using this tutorial :

[Please Click Here.](http://ubuntudroid.blogspot.in/2013/04/sending-files-with-xmppframework-and.html)

and the code which i am using :

```
- (void)sendToOtherDevice:(NSData *)fileData receiverJid:(NSString *)receiverJid
{
    XMPPJID *jid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:receiverJid];

     XMPPSIFileTransfer *sifiletransfer = [[XMPPSIFileTransfer alloc] init];
    [sifiletransfer initiateFileTransferTo:jid withData:fileData];

    NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/spark",receiverJid];
    NSString *jabbarID = [[[[self appDelegate] xmppStream] myJID] bare];
     XMPPJID *senderjid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:jabbarID];

    //[TURNSocket setProxyCandidates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:s, nil]];
   // [TURNSocket setProxyCandidates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:s,jabbarID, nil]];

    [TURNSocket setProxyCandidates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:jid.domain,senderjid.domain, nil]];

   // [TURNSocket setProxyCandidates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:jid.domain, nil]];
    //[TURNSocket setProxyCandidates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"111.11.111.111", nil]];

     TURNSocket *socket1 = [[TURNSocket alloc] initWithStream:[self xmppStream] toJID:jid];

   // [turnSockets addObject:turnSocket];
    [socket1 startWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

}


-(void)turnSocket:(TURNSocket *)sender didSucceed:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket
{
     [socket writeData:photoData withTimeout:60.0f tag:0];
     [socket disconnectAfterWriting];
}

- (void)turnSocketDidFail:(TURNSocket *)sender
{

    NSLog(@"Couldn't set up bytestream for file transfer!");
}
```

then on running this code i would get the following XMLStangas :

recieving Logs at android end :

```
12-03 10:26:59.359: D/SMACK(2021): 10:26:59 AM RCV  (1095046240): <iq type="set" id="47198142-86E8-41E2-9F68-40C52AFD5469" to="kadhirkarbonn@ip-10-123-60-876/smack" from="kadhirsduos@ip-10-123-60-876/smack"><si xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si" id="A0E740DE-CDF1-408E-ABE1-8F582A615F1E" mime-type="image/jpg" profile="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer"><file xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer" name="4_9.jpg" size="75261"/><feature xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/feature-neg"><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="form"><field var="stream-method" type="list-single"><option><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams</value></option></field></x></feature></si></iq>
12-03 10:26:59.399: I/Insert(2021): insert data with file name ===========4_9.jpg

12-03 10:27:01.749: I/Kadhir(2021): 4_9.jpg downloading started
12-03 10:27:01.779: D/SMACK(2021): 10:27:01 AM SENT (1095046240): <iq id="47198142-86E8-41E2-9F68-40C52AFD5469" to="kadhirsduos@ip-10-123-60-876/smack" from="kadhirkarbonn@ip-10-123-60-876/smack" type="result"><si xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si"><feature xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/feature-neg"><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit"><field var="stream-method"><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams</value></field></x></feature></si></iq>

12-03 10:27:02.039: D/SMACK(2021): 10:27:02 AM RCV  (1095046240): <iq type="get" id="ECF5E292-013C-45E5-8053-E2EA86219622" to="kadhirkarbonn@ip-10-123-60-876/smack" from="kadhirsduos@ip-10-123-60-876/smack"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/></iq>
12-03 10:27:02.049: D/SMACK(2021): 10:27:02 AM SENT (1095046240): <iq id="ECF5E292-013C-45E5-8053-E2EA86219622" to="kadhirsduos@ip-10-123-60-876/smack" type="result"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"><identity category="client" name="quytech" type="phone"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/caps"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/><feature var="jabber:iq:privacy"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/si"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/si"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/si"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb"/></query></iq>

12-03 10:27:02.739: D/SMACK(2021): 10:27:02 AM RCV  (1095046240): <iq type="set" to="kadhirkarbonn@ip-10-123-60-876/smack" id="E5132784-1493-458B-98B0-8E3902A541C0" from="kadhirsduos@ip-10-123-60-876/smack"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" sid="A0E740DE-CDF1-408E-ABE1-8F582A615F1E" mode="tcp"><streamhost jid="kadhirsduos@ip-10-123-60-876/smack" host="127.0.0.1" port="7777"/><streamhost jid="proxy.ip-10-123-60-876" host="10.123.60.876" port="7777"/></query></iq>


12-03 10:30:02.759: D/SMACK(2021): 10:30:02 AM RCV  (1095046240): <iq type="get" id="863-206317" from="ip-10-123-60-876" to="kadhirkarbonn@ip-10-123-60-876/smack"><ping xmlns="urn:xmpp:ping"/></iq>
12-03 10:30:02.779: D/SMACK(2021): 10:30:02 AM SENT (1095046240): <iq id="863-206317" to="ip-10-123-60-876" from="kadhirkarbonn@ip-10-123-60-876/smack" type="error"><error code="501" type="CANCEL"><feature-not-implemented xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>


12-03 10:30:12.259: D/SMACK(2021): 10:30:12 AM SENT (1095046240): <iq id="E5132784-1493-458B-98B0-8E3902A541C0" to="kadhirsduos@ip-10-123-60-876/smack" from="kadhirkarbonn@ip-10-123-60-876/smack" type="error"><error code="406" type="MODIFY"><not-acceptable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/><text xml:lang="en" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas">Could not establish socket with any provided host</text></error></iq>
```

Sending Logs at IOS ends :

```
2013-12-03 10:21:41:731 iPhoneXMPP[525:3523] SEND: <message type="chat" to="kadhirkarbonn@ip-10-123-60-876"><body>enter message here..</body></message>
2013-12-03 10:21:53.987 iPhoneXMPP[525:a0b] Sender ID is ==== kadhirsduos@ip-10-123-60-876/smack
2013-12-03 10:21:53:990 iPhoneXMPP[525:3523] SEND: <iq type="set" id="47198142-86E8-41E2-9F68-40C52AFD5469" to="kadhirkarbonn@ip-10-123-60-876/smack" from="kadhirsduos@ip-10-123-60-876/smack"><si xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si" id="A0E740DE-CDF1-408E-ABE1-8F582A615F1E" mime-type="image/jpg" profile="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer"><file xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer" name="4_9.jpg" size="75261"/><feature xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/feature-neg"><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="form"><field var="stream-method" type="list-single"><option><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams</value></option></field></x></feature></si></iq>
2013-12-03 10:21:56:721 iPhoneXMPP[525:5407] RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" id="47198142-86E8-41E2-9F68-40C52AFD5469" to="kadhirsduos@ip-10-123-60-876/smack" from="kadhirkarbonn@ip-10-123-60-876/smack" type="result"><si xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si"><feature xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/feature-neg"><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit"><field var="stream-method"><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams</value></field></x></feature></si></iq>
2013-12-03 10:21:56:721 iPhoneXMPP[525:a0b] iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate: xmppStream:didReceiveIQ:
2013-12-03 10:21:56.721 iPhoneXMPP[525:5407] didRecieveIQ*****************
2013-12-03 10:21:56.722 iPhoneXMPP[525:5407] IQ type === result
2013-12-03 10:21:56.723 iPhoneXMPP[525:5407] IQ type === si
2013-12-03 10:21:56.723 iPhoneXMPP[525:5407] IQ type === result/si
2013-12-03 10:21:56:724 iPhoneXMPP[525:5217] SEND: <iq type="get" id="ECF5E292-013C-45E5-8053-E2EA86219622" to="kadhirkarbonn@ip-10-123-60-876/smack" from="kadhirsduos@ip-10-123-60-876/smack"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/></iq>
2013-12-03 10:21:56:725 iPhoneXMPP[525:5217] SEND: <iq type="get" to="ip-10-123-60-876" id="41BB64C7-4216-4E7E-BC0F-CAEB7D093D45"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"/></iq>
2013-12-03 10:21:56:965 iPhoneXMPP[525:5407] RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="41BB64C7-4216-4E7E-BC0F-CAEB7D093D45" from="ip-10-123-60-876" to="kadhirsduos@ip-10-123-60-876/smack"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"><item jid="search.ip-10-123-60-876" name="User Search"/><item jid="conference.ip-10-123-60-876" name="Public Chatrooms"/><item jid="proxy.ip-10-123-60-876" name="Socks 5 Bytestreams Proxy"/><item jid="pubsub.ip-10-123-60-876" name="Publish-Subscribe service"/></query></iq>
2013-12-03 10:21:56:966 iPhoneXMPP[525:a0b] iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate: xmppStream:didReceiveIQ:
2013-12-03 10:21:56.966 iPhoneXMPP[525:5217] didRecieveIQ*****************
2013-12-03 10:21:56:967 iPhoneXMPP[525:3523] SEND: <iq type="get" to="proxy.ip-10-123-60-876" id="567B54C6-FE53-4A80-9DC6-13AA3E3C5445"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/></iq>
2013-12-03 10:21:56.967 iPhoneXMPP[525:5217] IQ type === result
2013-12-03 10:21:57:087 iPhoneXMPP[525:5217] RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" id="ECF5E292-013C-45E5-8053-E2EA86219622" to="kadhirsduos@ip-10-123-60-876/smack" type="result" from="kadhirkarbonn@ip-10-123-60-876/smack"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"><identity category="client" name="quytech" type="phone"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/caps"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/><feature var="jabber:iq:privacy"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/si"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/si"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/si"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb"/></query></iq>
2013-12-03 10:21:57:088 iPhoneXMPP[525:a0b] iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate: xmppStream:didReceiveIQ:
2013-12-03 10:21:57.089 iPhoneXMPP[525:3523] didRecieveIQ*****************
2013-12-03 10:21:57.090 iPhoneXMPP[525:3523] IQ type === result
2013-12-03 10:21:57:205 iPhoneXMPP[525:3523] RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="567B54C6-FE53-4A80-9DC6-13AA3E3C5445" from="proxy.ip-10-123-60-876" to="kadhirsduos@ip-10-123-60-876/smack"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"><identity category="proxy" name="SOCKS5 Bytestreams Service" type="bytestreams"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/></query></iq>
2013-12-03 10:21:57:205 iPhoneXMPP[525:a0b] iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate: xmppStream:didReceiveIQ:
2013-12-03 10:21:57:206 iPhoneXMPP[525:5217] SEND: <iq type="get" to="proxy.ip-10-123-60-876" id="F9F121E4-918C-4437-8B4A-E5568E123F57"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"/></iq>
2013-12-03 10:21:57.206 iPhoneXMPP[525:5407] didRecieveIQ*****************
2013-12-03 10:21:57.208 iPhoneXMPP[525:5407] IQ type === result
2013-12-03 10:21:57:325 iPhoneXMPP[525:5407] RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="F9F121E4-918C-4437-8B4A-E5568E123F57" from="proxy.ip-10-123-60-876" to="kadhirsduos@ip-10-123-60-876/smack"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"><streamhost jid="proxy.ip-10-123-60-876" host="10.123.60.876" port="7777"/></query></iq>
2013-12-03 10:21:57:326 iPhoneXMPP[525:a0b] iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate: xmppStream:didReceiveIQ:
2013-12-03 10:21:57:327 iPhoneXMPP[525:5407] SEND: <iq type="set" to="kadhirkarbonn@ip-10-123-60-876/smack" id="E5132784-1493-458B-98B0-8E3902A541C0" from="kadhirsduos@ip-10-123-60-876/smack"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" sid="A0E740DE-CDF1-408E-ABE1-8F582A615F1E" mode="tcp"><streamhost jid="kadhirsduos@ip-10-123-60-876/smack" host="127.0.0.1" port="7777"/><streamhost jid="proxy.ip-10-123-60-876" host="10.123.60.876" port="7777"/></query></iq>
2013-12-03 10:21:57.326 iPhoneXMPP[525:3523] didRecieveIQ*****************
2013-12-03 10:21:57.329 iPhoneXMPP[525:3523] IQ type === result
2013-12-03 10:23:16.726 iPhoneXMPP[525:a0b] SOCKS5 Connection failed!
2013-12-03 10:25:07:188 iPhoneXMPP[525:3523] RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" id="E5132784-1493-458B-98B0-8E3902A541C0" to="kadhirsduos@ip-10-123-60-876/smack" from="kadhirkarbonn@ip-10-123-60-876/smack" type="error"><error code="406" type="MODIFY"><not-acceptable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/><text xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas" lang="en">Could not establish socket with any provided host</text></error></iq>
2013-12-03 10:25:07:189 iPhoneXMPP[525:a0b] iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate: xmppStream:didReceiveIQ:
2013-12-03 10:25:07.189 iPhoneXMPP[525:3523] didRecieveIQ*****************
```

in this i have never get called turnSocket : didSuccedd method.  Can anyone tell me about what i am missing . Please help.

Comment: Use XEP-0096 for stream intialization. You can see http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0096.html for steam intialization and use same XEP-0065 for file transfer which you already have.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre i just not have XEP-0096 classes in my XMPPFrameWork Folder. Can u tell me from where i can put it in xmppframework.

Comment: can anyone tell me how can i use XEP0096 for StreamInialization in IOS

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre i have found XEP-0096 classes through this link :   https://github.com/adamk77/XMPPFramework/commit/49dd8f22e0d9ad3a1bf09443517201424eca445e                                                   But how i use these classes. Can u help me. I have edited my code.

Comment: Cool. Its looks like more than enough, But mine was different. As per above code You can intialize First XMPPSIFileTransfer class. And call this method - (void)initiateFileTransferTo:(XMPPJID*)to withData:(NSData*)data , you can customize this method according to your need like add some file name, type etc.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre thanks for comment.I will try with this approach.

Comment: don't Initialize TURNSockert again just use those delegate as used in XMPPSIFileTransfer. And read data in your NSMutableData.

Comment: @DeepakKumar Please write answer yourself, if you got solution. So it may be helpful for others.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre Please write answer, if you have any solution. So it may be helpful for others.

Comment: @sunilz definitely i will post solution after solving this issue.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre now i have sucessfully get notification of recieving file on other device. and i am getting some XMPPLOGS. but not transferring file . i have updated my question with that logs.

Comment: @DeepakKumar I adde answer. I am not sure It help you completely but It will help you to achieve file transfer.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre thanks for answer. i will try with this code.

Comment: @BhumeshwerKarte i have sucessfully implemented file sending on IOS. I have tested it by reciving file on Android and on Spark client. Now Can you give any info about how can i recieve file on IOS.

Comment: @DeepakKumar would you please help me how you are able to send file in ios, I have xep-0096 but every time i got "Turn connection Failed" error. I think its imp to open a connection before start init a transferring.

Comment: @DeepakKumar Hi deepak, Have you done file transferring/receiving using xmpp?

Comment: @RohitPathak and Deepak Kumar , Bhumeshwerekate   am also implemented as above but everey time am getting "TURN Connection failed!" please Help me . i strucked here please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Note: My XEP-0096 implementation is different from your's. Any way you created session so just get that ID 
It may help you:

```
- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq
{

    //**************** Handling the file transfer task *****************//
    NSLog(@"---------- Check if this IQ is for a File Transfer ----------");
   NSString *myFileTransferID = YOUR_SESSION_ID_GET_FROM_XEP--0096//[xmppFileTransfer xmppFileTransferResponse:(XMPPIQ *)iq];

    if ([myFileTransferID length]>0) {
        // Get the file size

        NSXMLElement *si = [iq elementForName:@"si"];
        NSXMLElement *file = [si elementForName:@"file"];
        if (file) {

//All are the attribute of file while creating section Id you need to take car for that
            filesize = [file attributeUInt32ValueForName:@"size"];
            received_FileOwner = [iq fromStr];
            received_FileType = [si attributeStringValueForName:@"mime-type"];
            received_FileName = [file attributeStringValueForName:@"name"];
        }
    }
    if([myFileTransferID length] > 0 && [[iq type] isEqualToString:@"result"]) {
        //  Create bytestream socket for File Transfer via XEP-0065
        TURNSocket *turnSocket = [[TURNSocket alloc] initWithStream:xmppStream toJID:[iq from] fileTransferSID:myFileTransferID];
        [turnSockets addObject:turnSocket];
        [turnSocket startWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    }
    else if([myFileTransferID length] > 0 && [[iq type] isEqualToString:@"set"]) {

        if ([TURNSocket isNewStartTURNRequest:iq]) {
            NSLog(@"TURN Connectio started:: to establish:: incoming file transfer request..");
            TURNSocket *turnSocket = [[TURNSocket alloc]initWithStream:sender incomingTURNRequest:iq withSessionID:myFileTransferID];
            [turnSocket startWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
            [turnSockets addObject:turnSocket];
        }
    }
}
```

TurnSocket delegates

```
- (void)turnSocket:(TURNSocket *)sender didSucceed:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket
{
    NSLog(@"Socket Suceeed Port For File Transfer: %d",socket.localPort);
    DDLogInfo(@"TURN Connection succeeded!");
    DDLogInfo(@"You now have a socket that you can use to send/receive data to/from the other person.");

    if ([imageDataFile length]>0) {  
        // fileTransferData data to write
        [socket fileTransferData withTimeout:200.0f tag:TAG_FILETRANSFER_STREAM];
        //        [turnSockets removeObject:sender];

    }
    else {
        fileTransferData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
        [socket readDataToLength:filesize withTimeout:290.0f tag:0];
    }
}

- (void)turnSocketDidFail:(TURNSocket *)sender
{
    DDLogInfo(@"TURN Connection failed!");

    [turnSockets removeObject:sender];
}


- (void)readRecievedData:(NSData*)data withTurnSocket:(TURNSocket *)receiver {

     [fileTransferData appendData:data];
     float progress = (float)[fileTransferData length] / (float)[data length];

     NSLog(@"Progresaa value is: %f",progress);
}
```

Comment: karte : my (void)turnSocket:(TURNSocket *)sender didSucceed:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket never called . can you tell me about the reason of this.

Comment: Please make usre you are using same session Id from XEP--096.

Comment: @ Bhumeshwer katre  can you give me the link of XMPPFrameWork which you are using in your project.

Comment: karte  now i am using same sid for file transfer. but now getting error of Could not establish socket with any provided host. Can u tell me why this happens ?

Comment: May be this error due to your OpenFire setting. Check And enable File transfer functionality.

Comment: Karte i have checked all the setting of openfire . it look like to good. now i have post both sender and reciever end logs. Please have a look and tell me if you found any problem.

Comment: i have edited my post with the logs of sending and on recieving ends.

Comment: @DeepakKumar please read http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0065.html and http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0096.html and see which stanza you are missing. I know File transfer is not the easy task. If your openfire have enabled File Transfer then problem with some stanza. May be you are missing some stanza check once with above link. First try with both iOS client only, if got success go with cross platform. And you have to handle sending as well receiving stanzas.

Comment: @BhumeshwerKarte i have sucessfully implemented file sending on IOS. I have tested it by reciving file on Android and on Spark client. Now Can you give any info about how can i recieve file on IOS.

Comment: @DeepakKumar check what are the stanza you got from spark for each sent stanza. And reply same stanza packet in order to receive file in iOS. I already added some condtion in 'didReceiveiq` to know when to start `Turn Scoket` to read data. Also added TurnSocket delegate `readRecievedData:(NSData*)data withTurnSocket:(TURNSocket *)receiver`.

Comment: @BhumeshwerKarte .atlast  Sucessfully Done FileTransfer. Thanks for support and guide me . Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DeepakKumar Cool brother, I appreciate your work. One thing also I want to let you know. If both user are online then only you can transfer file. If you want what's app like file transfer mechanism then need to go with http webservice.

Comment: Hi @BhumeshwerKarte . How are you. I have one another problem. I want to save chat message into coredata . i searched on google for this and found that through XEP-0136 we can store message in persistent storage. Have you any implemantaion of this or any tutorial of this that how can i use XEP-0136.

Comment: Hi @Bhumeshwerkatre will you please help me for file transfering, i'm unable to connect with the proxy server ip address which is required for transferring. error is Turn Socket Failed 404 item not found.

Comment: can anyone solved the file transfer issue ? please share code or any info related to this.please.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre I have used your code but I am getting error 406 from receiver. how can i solve that. please help me.

Comment: am also facing same problem.   can any one help me.. I could not get the expalinition .. And how to append the samemail.com/Samck