# FileTransfer by using XMPPFrameWork XEP-0065 and XEP-0096 in IOS

Tags: ios, file-transfer, xmppframework

i have a lot of search regarding file transfer in IOS. I am using XEP-0065 and XEP-0096 for FileTransfer . Code which i am using :

```
- (void)sendToOtherDevice:(NSData *)fileData receiverJid:(NSString *)receiverJid
{

     NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Smack",receiverJid];
    XMPPJID *jid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:s];

//    XMPPSIFileTransfer * sifiletransfer = [[XMPPSIFileTransfer alloc] initiateFileTransferTo:jid withData:fileData];

    XMPPSIFileTransfer *sifiletransfer = [[XMPPSIFileTransfer alloc] init];
    [sifiletransfer initiateFileTransferTo:jid withData:fileData];
    //XMPPJID *jid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:receiverJid];


    NSString *jabbarID = [[[[self appDelegate] xmppStream] myJID] bare];
     XMPPJID *senderjid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:jabbarID];

    //[TURNSocket setProxyCandidates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:s, nil]];
  // [TURNSocket setProxyCandidates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:s,jabbarID, nil]];

    [TURNSocket setProxyCandidates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:jid.domain,senderjid.domain, nil]];

   // [TURNSocket setProxyCandidates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:jid.domain, nil]];
    //[TURNSocket setProxyCandidates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"111.11.111.111", nil]];

     TURNSocket *socket1 = [[TURNSocket alloc] initWithStream:[self xmppStream] toJID:jid];

   // [turnSockets addObject:turnSocket];
    [socket1 startWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

}


-(void)turnSocket:(TURNSocket *)sender didSucceed:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket
{
     [socket writeData:photoData withTimeout:60.0f tag:0];
     [socket disconnectAfterWriting];
}

- (void)turnSocketDidFail:(TURNSocket *)sender
{

    NSLog(@"Couldn't set up bytestream for file transfer!");
}
```

and i found following XML stanzas :

```
2013-11-22 14:23:08:990 iPhoneXMPP[1434:6417] SEND: <iq type="get" to="lava1" id="A5D91010-C182-4BCB-A989-5DFF2C0B6AE8"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"/></iq>
2013-11-22 14:23:09:290 iPhoneXMPP[1434:6a07] RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="error" id="A5D91010-C182-4BCB-A989-5DFF2C0B6AE8" to="lava@example.com/368c5070" from="lava1"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"/><error code="404" type="cancel"><remote-server-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>
2013-11-22 14:23:09:291 iPhoneXMPP[1434:60b] iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate: xmppStream:didReceiveIQ:
2013-11-22 14:23:09:294 iPhoneXMPP[1434:6417] SEND: <iq type="get" to="example.com" id="7EB43464-63BC-4ADF-8B98-A1A15AB51DB3"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"/></iq>
2013-11-22 14:23:09:493 iPhoneXMPP[1434:400b] RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="7EB43464-63BC-4ADF-8B98-A1A15AB51DB3" from="example.com" to="lava@example.com/368c5070"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"><item jid="search.example.com" name="User Search"/><item jid="conference.example.com" name="Public Chatrooms"/><item jid="proxy.example.com" name="Socks 5 Bytestreams Proxy"/><item jid="pubsub.example.com" name="Publish-Subscribe service"/></query></iq>
2013-11-22 14:23:09:494 iPhoneXMPP[1434:60b] iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate: xmppStream:didReceiveIQ:
2013-11-22 14:23:09:504 iPhoneXMPP[1434:6417] SEND: <iq type="get" to="proxy.example.com" id="0DFDF89F-29DE-4477-AF5E-B67387DD973C"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/></iq>
2013-11-22 14:23:09:698 iPhoneXMPP[1434:400b] RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="0DFDF89F-29DE-4477-AF5E-B67387DD973C" from="proxy.example.com" to="lava@example.com/368c5070"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"><identity category="proxy" name="SOCKS5 Bytestreams Service" type="bytestreams"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/></query></iq>
2013-11-22 14:23:09:699 iPhoneXMPP[1434:60b] iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate: xmppStream:didReceiveIQ:
2013-11-22 14:23:09:701 iPhoneXMPP[1434:6a07] SEND: <iq type="get" to="proxy.example.com" id="63C74776-93A4-4C97-8CFC-63C57494E4F6"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"/></iq>
2013-11-22 14:23:09:903 iPhoneXMPP[1434:6417] RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="63C74776-93A4-4C97-8CFC-63C57494E4F6" from="proxy.example.com" to="lava@example.com/368c5070"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"><streamhost jid="proxy.example.com" host="10.128.63.123" port="7777"/></query></iq>
2013-11-22 14:23:09:904 iPhoneXMPP[1434:60b] iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate: xmppStream:didReceiveIQ:
2013-11-22 14:23:09:906 iPhoneXMPP[1434:6417] SEND: <iq type="set" to="lava1/Smack" id="BB87F255-51AF-49F1-B700-D009BFF8A057"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" sid="BB87F255-51AF-49F1-B700-D009BFF8A057" mode="tcp"><streamhost xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" jid="proxy.example.com" host="10.128.63.123" port="7777"/></query></iq>
2013-11-22 14:23:10:210 iPhoneXMPP[1434:6a07] RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="error" id="BB87F255-51AF-49F1-B700-D009BFF8A057" to="lava@example.com/368c5070" from="lava1/Smack"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" sid="BB87F255-51AF-49F1-B700-D009BFF8A057" mode="tcp"><streamhost jid="proxy.example.com" host="10.128.63.123" port="7777"/></query><error code="404" type="cancel"><remote-server-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>
2013-11-22 14:23:10:212 iPhoneXMPP[1434:60b] iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate: xmppStream:didReceiveIQ:
2013-11-22 14:23:10.213 iPhoneXMPP[1434:60b] Couldn't set up bytestream for file transfer!
```

Please Let me know what i am doing wrong. How Can i use XEP-0096 for FileTransfer.

Comment: Hi, I am getting same issue with "XEP-0096". Dear, If you get any solution, please share it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FileTransfer using XmppFrameWork in ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114783/filetransfer-using-xmppframework-in-ios)

Comment: Where can I find this XMPPFileTransfer file ?