# XMPPFramework - How to receive more than one file at a time?

Tags: ios, xmpp, file-transfer, xmppframework

I am developing application using XMPPFFramework. In my application one to one messaging functionality and one to one file sharing functionality is working perfectly.

Now, when my application receive two file at a time, one file is received and another file can not be received. my application sends "not acceptable" error to sender of another file. 
Now, How to accept receive that both file at a time.

Is it possible that another file can be placed in queue to receive at socket. If yes, how can I achieve this?

I am using **XEP-0096**  and **XEP-0065** for file transfer.

Comment: hai ashish chaklasiya , if u dont mind can u share the code and info for file sharing

Comment: @Suhail but where i have to post the code.

Comment: can u add as answer for this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114783/filetransfer-using-xmppframework-in-ios

Comment: @Suhail have you tried that code?

Comment: @Suhail i have make change in XEP-0096 XMPPSIFileTransfer class for file transfer.

Comment: Nope.now am not worked in xmpp.bt i want to know how it is.if u have a working code, its a great piece of information to my xmpp vocabulary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57821/discussion-between-suhail-and-ashish-chaklasiya).

Comment: @Suhail have you tried that code? found any mistake?

Comment: @Suhail okey....when ever you complete with file transfer, please inform me...

Comment: @Suhail yes i am trying with ejabberd server...

Comment: @Suhail nope... what happen?

Comment: come in chat...Let us continue this discussion in chat.